# Can you include an input field in a drop down list using select-2?

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select-2 for a list of states. I think its great and love the search input field it provides. I'm wondering though, is it possible to include another input so someone can manually enter information ~ I am hoping to add an "Other" or "International" field to this drop down so instead of including all the states / provinces / territories of the world I provide a field they can manually enter if the territiry if it's not included in the drop down list.

Is an input in a drop down even possible? I would like to try and stick with Select2 as I like the added features it provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add items manually to the select2 dropdown using the "tagging" function. See the link for more information: https://select2.org/tagging

Comment: Thanks for this but not exactly what I'm hoping to achieve. Ideally, I would like an added input along the lines of the search field in select2. Instead of it being just a search field though, it would be an optional input that people can submit their own info and send along with the form.